# How to backup entire hdfs data on local machine

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

We have small CDH cluster of 3 nodes with approx 2TB data. we are planning to expand it but before that current hadoop machines/racks are being relocated. And I just want to make sure I have backup in local machine, in case racks somehow are not relocated (or gets damaged on the way) and we have to install new ones. How do I ensure this?

I have taken snapshot of HDFS data from cloudera manager as backup and it resides on the cluster. But in this case I need to take backup of whole data on local machine or hard drive. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Distcp the data somewhere.

Posslible options:

- own solution - the temporary cluster - 2TB is not so much, hardware is cheap.
- managed solution - to the cloud. There are plenty of storage as a service providers. If not sure, S3 should work for You. Of course data transfer is Your cost, but there is always a trade of between managed service and own crafted.